# How to prove this conclusion in functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

**Question:** *Let $\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbf{N}}$ be a sequence in a normed space $\mathscr{X}$ such that for any $f\in \mathscr{X}^\ast$,*
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|f(x_i)|<\infty.
\end{equation}
*Now we want to show that $\exists M<\infty$ such that*
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|f(x_i)|\leqslant M\|f\|.
\end{equation}
**Here is my attempt:** We define on $\mathscr{X}^\ast$ that
\begin{equation}
T\colon \mathscr{X}^\ast\longrightarrow \mathbf{F},\,\,\, T(f)\colon\!=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(x_i).
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
|T(f)|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(x_i)\right|\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|f(x_i)|<\infty,\,\,\, \forall f\in\mathscr{X}^\ast.
\tag{$\ast$}
\end{equation}
Also $T$ is a linear map, so $T\in \mathscr{X}^{\ast\ast}$. Then by ($\ast$), $\|T\|<\infty$.

**I am stuck at here:** The best we can show now is
\begin{equation}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(x_i)\right|\leqslant \|T\|\cdot \|f\|.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to further show that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|f(x_i)|\leqslant \|T\|\cdot \|f\|.
\end{equation}
If not, how can I adjust my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track; the ideas are the same as yours just with a little tweak to account for the absolute value.

Here $$\ell_1= \left\{ (z_i)_{i=1}^\infty: \sum_{i=1}^\infty |z_i|<\infty\right\}, \qquad \| (z_i)_i\|_{\ell_1} =\sum_{i=1}^\infty |z_i|.$$

Consider the map $S: \mathscr{X}^* \to \ell_1$ given by $f\mapsto (f(x_i))_i$. By hypothesis this is well defined (i.e. $S(f)\in \ell_1$ for every $f\in \mathscr{X}^*$), so it's enough to show $S$ is bounded. Consider the auxiliary $S_N:\mathscr{X}^*\to \ell_1$ with $S_N(f):=(f(x_i))_{i=1}^N$. Since $\sup_N \| S_N(f)\|_{\ell_1} = \sup_N\sum_{i=1}^N |f(x_i)|<\infty$, by the uniform boundedness principle we get that there exists $M>0$ such that $\| S_N(f)\|_{\ell_1}\leq M\| f\|_{\mathscr{X}^*}$. This is what you want after taking the limit.

Comment: Thanks! That's a wonderful proof!